# toggle among three icons in html upon click

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a button that with every click - the icon will change. The button has next arrow, back arrow, stop icon. What would be the best way to handle the button so upon every click the icon will change.

HTML:

```
 <button (click)="toggleBtn()">
      <span *ngIf="selectedIcon='left'" class="icon-left"></span>
      <span *ngIf="selectedIcon='right'" class="icon-right"></span>
      <span *ngIf="selectedIcon='stop'" class="icon-stop"></span>
    </button>
```

Component:

```
 public ngOnInit() {
        this.selectedIcon="Both"; //default selection to display to user.
    }

 public toggleBtn(){
   // how should i handle the toggle? User a for loop in my component or switch? 
   // what would be the ideal way of achieving this. 
 }
```

Comment: What is supposed to appear when `selectedIcon` is `"Both"`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan - nothing it is just to enable that specific span with the selected icon. On page load it shows the stop icon, on click it will show the left icon, on another click it will show right icon. Should i have a for loop in my component and just pass the icon class of the selected toggle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use remainder operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()

```
//in your .ts declare a variable index
index:number=0;

//in your .html
<button (click)="index=(index+1)%3">
<span [ngClass]="{'icon-left':index==0,'icon-right':index==1,'icon-stop':index==2}">
```

**Updated** 
If you have several items, you need several variables. Normally you can have an array of object [{item:'uno',index:0}{item:'dos',index:0}..]. In a *ngFor="let item of myArray"> replace "index" by "item.index"

```
//In your .ts
myArray:any[]=[{desc:'uno',index:0},{desc:'dos',index:0}..];

//If you have an array of object but you don't have the property "index"
//You always can "map" the array to add the property
//e.g
anotherArray=["uno","dos"];

//transform the array
this.anotherArray=thia.anotherArray.map(x=>return{
       desc:x,
       index:0
})

<button *ngFor="let item of my array" (click)="item.index=(item.index+1)%3">
   <span [ngClass]="{
            'icon-left':item.index==0,
            'icon-right':item.index==1,
            'icon-stop':item.index==2}">{{item.desc}}
</button>
```

**Update two**
We can have diferent button but not in a *ngFor For that, using an array of index

```
//in ts
index:number[]=[0,0]
//in .html
<!--for the first button we use index[0]-->
<button (click)="index[0]=(index[0]+1)%3">
   <span [ngClass]="{
            'icon-left':index[0]==0,
            'icon-right':index[0]==1,
            'icon-stop':index[0]==2}">
</button>
<hr/>
<!--for the second button we use index[1]-->
<button (click)="index[1]=(index[1]+1)%3">
   <span [ngClass]="{
            'icon-left':index[1]==0,
            'icon-right':index[1]==1,
            'icon-stop':index[1]==2}">
</button>
<hr/>
```

Comment: Nice answer! I just tried it and it worked as expected. Also if i will be saving the icon selection.. Will it be enough to get the current index in the component and use that in my save?

Comment: I noticed that if i multiple items that each has the toggle button. The toggle gets applied to all items and not the specific item i am clicking on.

Comment: @bluePearl. update my answer, you need severals "index". You can use an array of number or add a property "index" to your list

Comment: I went ahead and tried your updated answer but now i am getting all three icons displayed for each list item and each of the three are clickable and toggle... not sure if i overlooked something but what is the `this.anotherArray` do?

Comment: Here is stackbiltz link to see what i am talking about.... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqcc8j

Comment: anotherArray is only one example of how, if we have an array , we can create an array of object with a new property.

Comment: would you happen to know why ur solution shows the set of icons three times?

Comment: I use a *ngFor, so the buttons arre repeated so many times the length of the array. If we want have, e.g. two buttons but not in an *ngFor, we use a simple array of numbers and replace index by index[0], for the first button and index[1] for the another one, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass attribute binding.

```
<button (click)="toggleBtn(selectedIcon)" [ngClass]="[selectedIcon=='left' ? 'icon-left' : '',  selectedIcon=='right' ? 'icon-right' : '', selectedIcon=='stop' ? 'icon-stop' : '']">
```

Inside Component:

```
selectedIcon;

toggleBtn(_sIcon){
   if(!_sIcon){
     this.selectedIcon = 'left';
   }else if(_sIcon === 'left){
     this.selectedIcon = 'right';
   }else if(_sIcon === 'right){
     this.selectedIcon = 'stop';
   }else if(_sIcon === 'stop){
     this.selectedIcon = 'left';
   }
}
```

Comment: not use a large chain of "if". a variable that get the values 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2... is enough. So use a % operator

Comment: OK. its fine. you can use switch case statement too.